# Tabula - AttributeError: module 'tabula' has no attribute 'read_pdf'

Tags: python, tabula

Trying to use the Tabula module to extract data from a pdf file - but I keep getting this error 'AttributeError: module 'tabula' has no attribute 'read_pdf'. I have the Tabula library downloaded and all and am running Python 3.8 - so I don't think it's something from my end?

Thoughts?

```
import tabula

pdf_path = 'file:///Users/example/Downloads/bpd_incident_history_search__2_%20(1).pdf'

dfs = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_path, pages='all')

print(dfs)
```

Comment: Is the name of that file also `tabula.py`? If so, rename it.

Comment: Did you run `pip install tabula` or `pip install tabula-py`?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the module you have installed is `tabula` instead of `tabula-py`, or you have both. `tabula` is not what you want - it's a different library.
Try running this:

```
python -m pip uninstall tabula
```

and then

```
python -m pip install tabula-py
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import analysis as tb
from tabula.io import read_pdf

pdf_path = "path/yourpdf.pdf"

data = tb.read_pdf(pdf_path, stream=True, pages =1, password='your password if be else remove this block')

print(data)
```